# Multiple IF statements with similar criteria JAVA

Tags: java

```
if (currencyChosen.equals("RANDOM3") & convertTo.equals("RANDOM3"))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAME SENTENCE");

else if (currencyChosen.equals("RANDOM2") & convertTo.equals("RANDOM2"))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAME SENTENCE");

else if (currencyChosen.equals("RANDOM") & convertTo.equals("RANDOM"))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAME SENTENCE");
```

If I had a code like this with multiple, but similar if statements with different if criteria, is there a way to make it more short and neat?

Comment: extract a method maybe. Note that you should always use braces for if/else

Comment: You can do an overall check that `currencyChosen` is equal to `convertTo`; then you only need to check the value of one of them with respect to the literal. (Oh, except that there is a space in the first case - is that intentional?)

Comment: Is the difference between "RANDOM3" and "RANDOM 3" in the first example deliberate?

Comment: Can you give more details about the context here? Often the most appropriate way to refactor code depends on the bigger picture.

Comment: Oh sorry it isn't deliberate, and for the braces I was having a problem when I used them but when I took it out they worked fine... I might have to go back and add them later.

Comment: I'm having to write a basic converter and I was trying to output that, for example, choosing "Convert from US dollars to US dollars" would output "You can't perform that action" and I would have to repeat it 5 more times. I thought it kind of looked messy and was wondering if there was a way to shorten it.

Comment: @jkjk: For that test, why do you need to check against each currency? Why not just check for `if (currencyChosen.equals(convertTo))`?

Comment: @jkjk you are missing an additional `&` sign inside of each `if` statement

Comment: @specializt: It's still valid code. I agree it would be better to make it short-circuiting, but it still *works* at the moment.

Comment: using non-short-circuiting operators rarely is useful ... i saw things like that in embedded control software -- in which it was necessary to execute all of the operations because some old, unmaintained library refused to work otherwise. I made the experience that usage of these operators (on Boolean) usually is an indicator for bad programming _(or even worse : bad programmers)_.

Comment: @specializt: But just saying "you are missing an additional `&`" doesn't actually help the OP become a better programmer. It doesn't explain anything about what you consider to be wrong. It implies the code is invalid (which it isn't) and doesn't say anything about the benefits of short-circuiting. There are certainly helpful ways of pointing out that `&&` is probably what the OP intended, but I don't think your original comment comes under that "helpful" category...

Comment: @specializt: Sure, if that's the main point of the question... but without *any* explanation, your comment simply didn't add anything useful, IMO... whereas just a little bit more effort you could have a) made it clear you understood that this code was still valid (that's not clear from your original comment); b) given the OP at least enough information about the difference between `&` and `&&` to find more details easily. At the moment it just looks like a criticism with no desire to help the OP improve.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you probably want something like:

```
private static final List<String> VALID_CURRENCIES = 
    Arrays.asList("RANDOM", "RANDOM2", "RANDOM3");

...

if (currencyChosen.equals(convertTo) && VALID_CURRENCIES.contains(currencyChosen)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAME SENTENCE");
}
```

Adjust the variable names to suit your context. You could also use a `Set<String>` instead of a `List<String>` if the order is never important... with a small number of valid options it won't make much difference in performance though. The O(1) nature of a `HashSet` vs O(N) of a list only matters when N becomes large. Of course, you may want to use `Set<String>` anyway, to make the intention of treating it *only* as a set clearer. My guess is that you may well have another reason to have a list of the valid currencies (in a particular order) anyway though - in which case, use that list here as well.

However, with your description of the context:

> I'm having to write a basic converter and I was trying to output that, for example, choosing "Convert from US dollars to US dollars" would output "You can't perform that action

it sounds like you probably only need

```
if (currencyChosen.equals(convertTo)) {
    ...
}
```

If you're somehow allowing `currencyChosen` and `convertTo` to not be valid, you should check for that first:

```
if (!VALID_CURRENCIES.contains(currencyChosen)) {
    // Display error for invalid source currency
    return;
}

if (!VALID_CURRENCIES.contains(convertTo)) {
    // Display error for invalid target currency
    return;
}

if (currencyChosen.equals(convertTo)) {
    // Display error for source == target
    return;
}
```

Basically, try to make your error conditions orthogonal as far as you can.

Comment: Use a hashset for O(1).

Comment: @McKevin: In this case, it may well actually be slower than using a list. There are only three entries, and they differ in length - why bother computing the hash code of anything? I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

With a method (assumes `currencyChosen` and `convertTo` are fields):

```
private boolean foo(String input) {  // TODO: use more meaningful names
   return currencyChosen.equals(input) && convertTo.equals(input)
}
```

then

```
if (foo("RANDOM3") || foo("RANDOM2") || foo("RANDOM")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAME SENTENCE");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could extract it to something like the following

```
if (currencyChosen.equals(convertTo)) {
    final boolean random3 = isRandom(currencyChosen, "RANDOM3");
    final boolean random2 = isRandom(currencyChosen, "RANDOM2");
    final boolean random = isRandom(currencyChosen, "RANDOM");

    if (random3 || random2 || random) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAME SENTENCE");
    }
}

// ....

private static boolean isRandom(String currencyChosen, String random) {
    return currencyChosen.equals(random);
}
```

Comment: Minor nit: this doesn't short circuit the evaluation of the three booleans. I'd just inline the isRandom calls in the conditional.

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast answer. Is there a way to give thanks? Sorry im new to this website.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thats true, I only do it in cases like this where readability is a bit more important then performance.

Comment: @jkjk Upvote this answer if you think it is good (if you have enough reputation) and [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.